# EF 6 Enable-Migrations Can't Find Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to set up EF code first migrations in EF 6.1.3 - .NET 4.5.

My solution has multiple projects in it, the startup project being `Songbirds.Web`. I have created a Project named `Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework` to contain my repositories, database context, and migrations.

I created my context class:

```
namespace Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework
{
    public class SongbirdsDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IUnitOfWork
    {
        public SongbirdsDbContext()
            : this("name=SongbirdsDBContext")
        {
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The entire solution builds properly with no errors.

I go into the Project Manager Console and set the Default Project to be the `Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework` and run the `enable-migrations` command and I get the following error:

```
PM> enable-migrations
No context type was found in the assembly 'Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework'.
```

I tried specifying the Context Type explicitly with the following result:

```
PM> enable-migrations -ContextTypeName Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework.SongbirdsDbContext
The context type 'Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework.SongbirdsDbContext' was not found in the assembly 'Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework'.
```

The SongbirdsDbContext is part of the Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework project.  Any ideas what I've done wrong and why it isn't recognizing the context?

Comment: Do you have the connection set up in the `Web.config`?

Comment: I have the connection string defined for the context if that's what you mean?  Is there something else that needs to be done to set up the connection?

Comment: Not sure, but the connection string is what I was alluding to yes. Just making sure you did in fact have it configured properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer through trial and error.
I first changed the context class to inherit from the DbContext class instead of IdentifyDbContext:

```
public class SongbirdsDbContext : DbContext
```

And re-ran the `enable-migrations` command to find the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

After adding the appropriate reference to the required assembly, I was able to successfully enable migrations.  I'm not sure why inheriting from DbContext showed this error while inheriting from IdentityDbContext did not.

Comment: >>  I'm not sure why inheriting from DbContext showed this error while inheriting from IdentityDbContext did not.

Do you have this around the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have your default project set to the project with the EF context.

Comment: I set the default project in the package manager console window.  It is pointing that the project that contains the SongbirdsDbContext class.

Comment: I just re-read your question, and you said you already did that.  My bad.

Comment: Just for clarification, did you have your Default project set to Songbirds.Dal or Songbirds.Web?

Answer (score 0):

Try just running

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework
```

adding .songBirdsContext to the end might have been the problem.

Comment: It didn't work. The context type 'Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework' was not found in the assembly 'Songbirds.Dal.EntityFramework'.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this on my side is that I had just created a project but I hadn't build it yet. So building my project then re-runing the command worked